# Can't overload "<<" operator

Tags: c++, output, overloading

Everywhere I look I see everyone overloading the << operator in a few lines, it seems very simple, but for some reason, overloading the << operator in my code does nothing.

In my .h I have:

```
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& test);
```

And in my .cpp I have:

```
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const DeckOfCards& deck) {
    out << "oi"; //just testing with a normal string before i try methods
    return out;
}
```

And finally in the main function I have:

```
Test* test = new Test();
std::cout << "output is: " << test << std::endl;
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not use new/delete needlessly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about trying this:

```
std::cout << "output is: " << *test << std::endl;
```

In your code, you are `cout`ing the pointer, not the object.

Comment: Wow I put the asterix after test and not before... Thanks for the quick reply.